# How to display data in pop-up windiw Fancy?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following part of code in controller:

```
$scope.open = function () {
            $scope.modal = $fancyModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                themeClass: "ddd",
                resolve: {
                    subcategories: function () {

                        return $scope.subcategories;
                    }
                }

            });
        };
```

It is called when I do click.

So, HTML templat file is:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 content-white-background" id="settings-page" ng-controller="CategoryController">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">

            <div id="modal-categories">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3>$$subcategories.title$$</h3>
                </div>

            </div>
        </script>
</div>
```

Why I can not see variable `$$subcategories$$` inside template `myModalContent.html`?

Comment: i think it sould be `<h3>{{subcategories.title}}</h3>`

Comment: No,  I use `$interpolateProvider` as `$$`